# Display text depending on dropdown choice

Tags: jquery, html

How can I read the selected option and display a `div` depending on the choice:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Package 1</option>
    <option value="2">Package 2</option>
    <option value="3">Package 3</option>
    <option value="4">Package 4</option>
    <option value="5">Package 5</option>
    <option value="6">Package 6</option>
</select>
```

If you can have a look at this fiddle and integrate the code in it : http://jsfiddle.net/JVzCt/

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to have it update when they change the selection

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeanWhitehouse/8L5kG/

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Package 1</option>
        <option value="2">Package 2</option>
        <option value="3">Package 3</option>
        <option value="4">Package 4</option>
        <option value="5">Package 5</option>
        <option value="6">Package 6</option>
    </select>

<div class='output'></div>

    <script>
$('#myselect').change(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();

                $('.output').html('package ' + val);   

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an id to the `select` element. For example:

```
<select id="optionsPackage" .../>
```

Now do something like:

```
var selected = $('#optionsPackage').val();
if(selected=='1')
{
    $('#divID').show(); //or whatever corresponding DIV id 
}
```

Comment: Can you integrate your code in the followin JSFiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/JVzCt/

Comment: @user3025379 here: http://jsfiddle.net/JVzCt/1/ - pay attention to the new divs I added and the `select.change` function.

Comment: This is working but can you apply it to work on every duplicate one you add ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="myselect">
        <option value="1">Package 1</option>
        <option value="2">Package 2</option>
        <option value="3">Package 3</option>
        <option value="4">Package 4</option>
        <option value="5">Package 5</option>
        <option value="6">Package 6</option>
    </select>
```

JS:

```
value = $( "#myselect" ).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').val();
```

will grab the value.

Then let's say you have 6 hidden divs with an ID of "Package-X", where X is a number.

You can simply do:

```
$('#Package-' + $('select').val()).show();
```

You don't *need* an ID on your select as Icarus suggested, but code will be cleaner and better with it on as there is no chance of grabbing the wrong select element.